# Parse SOAP in Go

Tags: xml, go, soap, wsdl

I just started learning Go. I want to parse a SOAP service. I have difficulty parsing the XML. Here's the XML:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

  <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">SECRET</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>

  <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <OTA_HotelAvailNotifRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" EchoToken="abc123" Version="1.0" TimeStamp="2005-08-01T09:30:47+08:00">
      <AvailStatusMessages HotelCode="HOTEL">
        <AvailStatusMessage BookingLimit="10">
          <StatusApplicationControl Start="2010-01-01" End="2010-01-14" InvTypeCode="A1K" RatePlanCode="GLD"/>
        </AvailStatusMessage>
      </AvailStatusMessages>
    </OTA_HotelAvailNotifRQ>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>

</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And here's the code I write to parse the XML:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
)

type Envelope struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    SOAPENV string   `xml:"xmlns:SOAP-ENV,attr"`
    XSD     string   `xml:"xmlns:xsd,attr"`
    XSI     string   `xml:"xmlns:xsi,attr"`
    SOAPENC string   `xml:"xmlns:SOAP-ENC,attr"`
    NS9132  string   `xml:"xmlns:ns9132,attr"`
    Header  Header   `xml:"SOAP-ENV:Header"`
}

type Header struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"SOAP-ENV:Header"`
    Security Security `xml:"wsse:Security"`
}

type Security struct {
    XMLName        xml.Name `xml:"wsse:Security"`
    MustUnderstand string `xml:"soap:mustUnderstand,attr"`
    WSSE           string `xml:"xmlns:wsse,attr"`
    SOAP           string `xml:"xmlns:soap,attr"`
    UsernameToken struct {
        XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"wsse:UsernameToken"`
        Username string `xml:"wsse:Username"`
        Password string `xml:"wsse:Password"`
    }
}

func main() {

    Soap := []byte(`<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

  <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">SECRET</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>

  <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <OTA_HotelAvailNotifRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" EchoToken="abc123" Version="1.0" TimeStamp="2005-08-01T09:30:47+08:00">
      <AvailStatusMessages HotelCode="HOTEL">
        <AvailStatusMessage BookingLimit="10">
          <StatusApplicationControl Start="2010-01-01" End="2010-01-14" InvTypeCode="A1K" RatePlanCode="GLD"/>
        </AvailStatusMessage>
      </AvailStatusMessages>
    </OTA_HotelAvailNotifRQ>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>

</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>`)

    res := &Envelope{}
    err := xml.Unmarshal(Soap, res)

    fmt.Println(res.Header.Security.UsernameToken.Username, err)
}
```

Why is it returns `nil`. I expect to get the username value from it. Also why can't I use `xml:"SOAP-ENV:Envelope"` for XMLName on Envelop struct? The error message is `expected element type <SOAP-ENV:Envelope> but have <Envelope>`

My Go version is 1.8.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `xml:"UsernameToken"` instead of `xml:"wsse:UsernameToken"`, `xml:"wsse:Security"` -> `xml:"Security"`, etc.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
)

type Envelope struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    Header  Header
}

type Header struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"Header"`
    Security Security `xml:"Security"`
}

type Security struct {
    XMLName        xml.Name `xml:"Security"`
    MustUnderstand string `xml:"mustUnderstand,attr"`
    WSSE           string `xml:"wsse,attr"`
    SOAP           string `xml:"soap,attr"`
    UsernameToken struct {
        XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"UsernameToken"`
        Username string `xml:"Username"`
        Password string `xml:"Password"`
    }
}

func main() {

    Soap := []byte(`<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

  <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">SECRET</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>

  <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <OTA_HotelAvailNotifRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" EchoToken="abc123" Version="1.0" TimeStamp="2005-08-01T09:30:47+08:00">
      <AvailStatusMessages HotelCode="HOTEL">
        <AvailStatusMessage BookingLimit="10">
          <StatusApplicationControl Start="2010-01-01" End="2010-01-14" InvTypeCode="A1K" RatePlanCode="GLD"/>
        </AvailStatusMessage>
      </AvailStatusMessages>
    </OTA_HotelAvailNotifRQ>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>

</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>`)

    res := &Envelope{}
    err := xml.Unmarshal(Soap, res)

    fmt.Println(res.Header.Security.UsernameToken.Username, err)
}
```

Output: `USERNAME <nil>`

Comment: It's works. Is there any explanation why I can omit `wsse:` part?

Comment: @otezz: `wsse:` is a [namespace prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace), it's not part of the element name.

Comment: @JimB now I get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like an XML problem. BayRinat's answer addresses this issue. Generally, you could try a SOAP library: https://golanglibs.com/top?q=soap

https://github.com/mfenniak/go-soap

https://github.com/justwatchcom/goat

https://github.com/fiorix/wsdl2go